# URL rewrite for Subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The situation is simple. I create a wildcard subdomain in my cpanel that goes something like this: *.mysite.com.

I can load the page but I want to take the value of the wildcard as a parameter of GET so the page can actually display the relevant contents based on that GET value.

So what i want to know is if its possible to have a rewrite rule that allows me to do the following.

Get: $_GET['store']=='andystore' from the url: http://andystore.mysite.com

Comment: Okay. You're talking about rewrite rules but the only code you've supplied is the `$_GET` method of PHP. Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# capture first part of host name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
# make sure store= query parameter isn't there
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)store= [NC]
# rewrite to current URI?store=backererence #1 from host name
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?store=%1 [L,QSA]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

#### [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

Comment: Thanks. Worked! Sweet and easy.

Comment: Is it possible to just briefly explain so i and the rest of the noobs, who might have similar questions, viewing can understand the code a little?

Comment: I have same question, but using cakephp,  
I have tried your code but it redirected to other page. and show error message "Sorry. The website you are looking for is unavailable "  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212025/url-rewrite-create-subdomain-in-cakephp

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://$1.mysite.com [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You might want to explain what this does. SO exists to educate, not just answer quetions.